# reading the contents of the file and splitting using ksh

Tags: file, split, ksh

We're using a ksh script for installing one product.

I've another config file, I'd need to read this configuration file from my main script

Content of the Configuration file:

> BPWS_Instance_1:Linux:x86_64:YES:/hosting/download:BPWS_Linux_64.jar paymon_Instance_1:Linux:i686:YES:/hosting/download:paymon_Linux_32.jar

So now in my main script after reading the configuration file If I've **BPWS_Instance_1** ( this is the instance name ) which is running ( **YES** = *Running* ) on the Linux OS 64 bit processor ( **Linux:x86_64** ) then I'd need to get the BPWS_Linux_64.jar file from the location **/hosting/download**.

Can someone help me with this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try somethig like this

#!/bin/ksh

CONF_FILE=your conf file path

while read LINE

do

```
echo "${LINE}" | grep "^BPWS_Instance_1:Linux:x86_64:YES:" >/dev/bull 2>&1

if [[ $? -eq 0 ]] then

    DOWNLOAD_PATH=`echo $LINE | cut -d: -f5`

    DOWNLOAD_FILE=`echo $LINE | cut -d: -f6`

    # Do your copy there
    # cp "${DOWNLOAD_PATH}/${DOWNLOAD_FILE} your path
fi
```

done < "$CONF_FILE"